# How to call `p5.js` draw method on button click in angular

Tags: angularjs, p5.js

I am using `p5.js` & below is the code for drawing.

```
sketch(p: any) {
    p.setup = function () {
      var canvas = p.createCanvas(700, 400);
      canvas.parent('sketchdiv');
      p.strokeWeight(5);
      p.stroke(0);
    };
    p.draw = () => {
      if (p.mouseIsPressed) {
        if (p.mouseButton === p.LEFT) {
          p.line(p.mouseX, p.mouseY, p.pmouseX, p.pmouseY);
        }
      }
    };

    p.mouseReleased = () => {
      console.log("mouseReleased");
    };
}
```

but i want to draw only on when user selects pencil (an icon click)

```
<span (click)="pencil()">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
</span>
```

```
  isPencil: boolean = false;
  pencil() {
    console.log("Pencil is chosen");
    this.isPencil = true;
  }
```

But I am not able to access this `isPencil` variable inside `sketch`. How to do that ? how to seperate `setup()` & `draw()` from instance mode in angular?

**Please help/guide**